# Developer account email access

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm not quite sure that this is the right place to ask my question, but I've searched all over and haven't been able to figure out my problem. Google Support told me to post in ththe AdWords API forum, and they sent me here. I have a developer account used for the Analytics API (520577192276@developer.gserviceaccount.com), which was set up several years ago by a colleague who is no longer with the company. I've looked for the password for this account all over the place, but I haven't been able to find it. I tried recovering the password, however the recovery email is the same as the email on the account (520577192276@developer.gserviceaccount.com), and since I can't get in to that account, I can't check the email.

We're very close to reaching the limit of 100 Google accounts for the 520577192276@developer.gserviceaccount.com account. I tried requesting an increase to 200, but I was told I needed to approve the request via email using the 520577192276@developer.gserviceaccount.com account, which as you see above, I'm not able to access.

It looks like this account is linked to another account we use (rioseo.ga@gmail.com) with Google Analytics and Google My Business. When I log into the Google Developer Console with the rioseo.ga@gmail.com account, I can see the API enabled for the 520577192276@developer.gserviceaccount.com, and all the other details related to the Analytics API. Is there any way I can recover or reset the password for 520577192276@developer.gserviceaccount.com so I can approve an increase in user accounts?

Comment: That email belongs to a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount); there is no password. It has no gmail/email account. Service accounts are fake users that can access resources through use of the API, such as the Analytics accounts its been added to.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the information I needed!